# Golang: Autocomplete missing interface methods

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am currently working on a go project where I define an interface to use in another file. My workflow works but I'm confused at either why there doesn't seem to be any "auto-complete" for protocols or why I cannot find it, I am using VSCode.

First of all, I am not fluent in go at all so if I misuse the term "object" for example that's because I don't know any better.

Let's say the interface looks like that:

```
type TestInterface interface {
    Function1()
}
```

and my function to pass an object of that interface to looks like that

```
func Start(obj TestInterface) {
    ...
```

Now, in order to define a type that I can construct an object of, I do

```
type TestInterfaceType int
```

and because I have to conform to the interface defined, I need to apply these functions to my "new" type

```
func (e TestInterfaceType) Function1() {
    fmt.Println("Test")
}
```

I am then able to construct an object

```
var testInterfaceTypeObject TestInterface

testInterfaceTypeObject = TestInterfaceType(1)
```

and passing that object to my `Start()` function above which expects a type of that interface works fine since the object of my "new type" has the functions defined that are defined on the interface.

---

Everything until here works as I have expected, or at least it works for me.

Now if I add another function to the `TestInterface` but I do not apply that new function to my `TestInterfaceType`, I see an error coming up that is `InvalidIfaceAssign`:

> InvalidIfaceAssign occurs when a value of type T is used as an
> interface, but T does not implement a method of the expected
> interface.

I understand why this is happening, I also have to do the `func (e TestInterfaceType) ...` for my new function but here is my question:

Is there a way to automatically generate empty mock functions for the missing functions? In Java for example, the IDE offers me to add the missing functions (without functionality of course, but at least they are there, ready for me to write logic into them)?

In other words, once I add `Function2()` to `TestInterface`, can I make it automatically do

```
func (e TestInterfaceType) Function2() {
    
}
```

wherever I use that interface?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with VS Code's official Go extension, but there is another: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ricardoerikson.vscode-go-impl-methods

Comment: Thank you for answering! Apparently this command does the same: https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/vs-code-go-auto-generate-missing-method-func-stubs/25050 haven't been able to figure out how to use it yet but both ways seem a bit uncomfortable comparing to how it is in java but maybe that's the difference between IDE and "Editor" that VSCode is